# What is the play sound item is touched setting?

Tags: audio, screen, vibration

I was looking in settings, and I saw a weird setting option. In "sounds and vibrations " under settings there something know as

> Play a sound when certain items are touched on the screen

Now my question is, how is this useful, what is this, and what items triger this sound?

Im using a Samsung J3 2016 with android 7.1.1

Sorry if I have mistakes, im using mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option serves as sound feedback when tapping on your screen, for instance on your keyboard, or (usually) when navigating menus/options in the Settings app.

(My opinion : while useful, be wary of not activating that option in public places/transports, as it's usually very irritating for *other* people to hear *your* tapping feedback)